# Date extension javascript get month name

Tags: javascript, date, extension-methods

I'm struggling to make a extension on the date object to return the current month in name. It should return (January) if the method d.getMonthText() is called.

I've searched for extension online but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just map `date.getMonth()` method value to month values

```js
Date.prototype.getMonthText = function() {
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return months[this.getMonth()];
}

var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonthText();
console.log(month);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although not recommended, you can add methods to almost any javascript built–in object through its prototype property.

```
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
    let months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

    return months[this.getMonth()];
};
```

Then just use it:

```
let date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonthName();
```

Comment: Wow, we have super similar answer

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an option, you might consider *toLocaleString* which should support the ECMA 402 internationalisation API. It's not ubiquitous yet but worth considering for the future as it will return the month name in any language using the ISO 639-1 language codes:

```js
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(lang) {
  // Default language is English
  lang = lang || 'en-GB';
  return this.toLocaleString(lang, {month:'long'});
}

console.log(new Date().getMonthName())        // English (default)

console.log(new Date().getMonthName('ar-sy')) // Arabic

console.log(new Date().getMonthName('es-py')) // Spanish
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go in a very basic way.. This function will return you the name of Month

```
<script>
function getMonthText(){
var month;
 switch (new Date().getMonth()) {
   case 0:
     month= "Jan";
     break;
   case 1:
     month= "Feb";
     break;
   case 2:
     month= "March";
     break;
   case 3:
     month= "April";
     break;
   case 4:
     month= "May";
     break;
   case 5:
     month= "June";
     break;
   case  6:
     month= "July";
     break;
   case  7:
     month= "August";
     break;
   case  8:
     month= "Sep";
     break;
   case  9:
     month= "Oct";
     break;
   case  10:
     month= "Nov";
     break;
   case  11:
     month= "Dec";
     break;
}}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 6 version :

```
getPreviousMonth(monthBefore) {
    let monthList = [];
    let date = new Date();
    for (let i = 0; i < monthBefore; i++) {
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
        monthList.push(date.toLocaleString('en-us', {
            month: 'long',
        }));
    }
    return monthList;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could monkey-patch the Date prototype object and implement an extension method:

```js
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
  return "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December".split(",")[this.getMonth()];
}
```